# Getting error in angular application in a chrome plugin

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension using angular (v7.2.11) and I'm getting the following exception:

```js
polyfills.js:5065 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__zone_symbol__define' of null
    at Object.patchCallbacks (polyfills.js:5065)
    at patchCustomElements (polyfills.js:6011)
    at polyfills.js:6103
    at Function.push.../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.__load_patch (polyfills.js:2947)
    at polyfills.js:6102
    at polyfills.js:2858
    at Object.../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js (polyfills.js:2860)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:79)
    at Module../src/polyfills.ts (polyfills.js:6303)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:79)
```

Comment: Maybe zone.js doesn't work with extensions? Is this a content script?

Comment: Yes, It's a content script

Comment: In that case it won't work because only DOM is shared between the page and the content script, but not JavaScript context/environment (content scripts run in an isolated world). Theoretically it may be possible to make zone.js work properly but I suspect it'd be a nontrivial effort. Consider using an iframe exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) that points to an html file inside your extension where you'll be able to use your scripts normally.

Answer (score 0):

- Installed @webcomponents/custom-elements:

```sh
npm install @webcomponents/custom-elements --save
```

- in polyfills.ts imported it before zone.js:

```js
...
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
...
```